# Set date for JQuery UI Calendar bound to DIV?

Tags: jquery-ui, vb.net-2010

Can I set the date on a JQuery UI Calendar which is not bound to a textbox or a label but to a  from codebehind?

```
<script>
    $("#COICalendar").datepicker();
</script>

<div id="COICalendar" class="ui-datepicker-calendar"></div>
```

Comment: something like this would work  `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/15/2012" );` ?

Comment: I want to do it from codebehind using vb.net